# Duplicate a table column in the correct order (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like:

| it.name | ReqTime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 - Hop:IP | 5 |
| 2 - Hop:IP | 1 |
| 3 - Hop:IP | 22 |
| 4 - Hop:IP | 15 |
| 5 - Hop:IP | 30 |
| 6 - Hop:IP | 30 |

```
select it.name as target_app, hsu.value as req_rate
from items it 
inner join hosts hs on hs.hostid = it.hostid
inner join history hsu on hsu.itemid = it.itemid
where it.name like '% - Hop%' and to_timestamp(hsu.clock) BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 MINUTES' AND NOW() 
order by it.name
```

How can get a table like this? :

| it.name | it.name (Start from the 2nd hop) | ReqTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 - Hop:IP | 2 - Hop:IP | 5 |
| 2 - Hop:IP | 3 - Hop:IP | 1 |
| 3 - Hop:IP | 4 - Hop:IP | 22 |
| 4 - Hop:IP | 5 - Hop:IP | 15 |
| 5 - Hop:IP | 6 - Hop:IP | 30 |

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Where does `6 - Hop:IP` come from?

Comment: You can use `lead/lag` provided you have an ordering column or expression.

Comment: DBMS - PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `LEAD` window function.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select it.name as target_app, 
           LEAD(it.name) OVER(ORDER BY it.name) the_2nd_hop
           hsu.value as req_rate
    from items it 
    inner join hosts hs on hs.hostid = it.hostid
    inner join history hsu on hsu.itemid = it.itemid
    where it.name like '% - Hop%' and to_timestamp(hsu.clock) BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 MINUTES' AND NOW() 
) t1
WHERE the_2nd_hop IS NOT NULL
order by target_app
```